# How to detect if MS word document has been closed

Tags: delphi

I have used the next code to open my document by using MS Word :

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil,
  PChar(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Data\Quotation-Terms-1.rtf'),
  nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

and i want to load my document inside my TRichEdit control after the user closed the MS Word document.

thank you.

Comment: Maybe you'd better use OLE automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pen the file as a TFileStream, passing fmShareExclusive as rights argument. If open is a success, then the file is not open in Word.

```
Success := FALSE;
try
    fs := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'Data\Quotation-Terms-1.rtf',
                             fmOpenReadWrite,
                             fmShareExclusive);
    Success := TRUE;
except
    on E:EFOpenError do
         Success := FALSE;
    else
         raise;
end;
if success then begin
    // More code
end;
```

It is possible that you may need to wait a few second before testing so that Word has time to load the file.

Comment: Yes finally it works , thank you .. but is there a way to get the Ms Word window handle?

Comment: How would getting a window handle help, and which window handle would you need

Comment: If i got the window handle then i will be able to check if this handle is 0 ( the window had been closed ).

Comment: @Issam On this website, only one question is allowed per post. So you'd better create a new question with a correct title and me and others will answer.